# Adding constraints to CPLEX not working C++ API

Tags: c++, cplex

After solving my model with CPLEX I would like to add further constraints to the model. I have a vector of requests `R`, with a corresponding variable `p_i` for each `i  in R` and a constraint `p_i = 1` (there are more variables and constraints which I have omitted here). After the first solve a new request appears for which I would like to create a new variable `p_{new_request}` and the corresponding constraint `p_{new_request} = 1`. I've tried this in two different ways, one way works using

```
model.add(p[rmap[new_request]] == 1);
```

the other one doesn't, i.e. the constraint is not added to the model.

```
accept.add(IloRange());
accept[rmap[new_request]] = IloRange(env,1,p[rmap[new_request]],1,name.str().c_str());
```

I need the second way, because I also need to remove certain constraints from the model once the request has been served, i.e.

```
accept[rmap[i]].end();
```

How can I do that properly?
Help is very much appreciated!!!

Here's the complete code:
(Since `R = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25,26}`, and I cannot access `p[25]` as `p` is a vector of size 12, I have created a map `rmap`. )

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
ILOSTLBEGIN

int main(){
  
  bool solved;

  // vector R contains all requests
  std::vector <int> R = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25,26};
  // use this unordered map to index variables p with requests
  std::unordered_map<int,int> rmap;
  int count = 0;
  for (const auto& i: R)
  {
    rmap[i] = count;
    count++;
  }

  int new_request;
  
  // use this stringstream to create variable and constraint names
  std::stringstream name;

  IloEnv             env;
  IloModel     model(env);
  IloNumVarArray p(env,R.size());
  IloRangeArray accept(env,R.size());
  
  for (const auto& i: R)
  {
    name << "p_" << i;
    p[rmap[i]] = IloNumVar(env, 0, 1, ILOBOOL, name.str().c_str()); 
    name.str("");
  }

  for (const auto& i : R)
  {
    name << "accept_" << i;
    accept[rmap[i]] = IloRange(env,1,p[rmap[i]],1,name.str().c_str()); 
    name.str(""); // Clean name
  }   
  model.add(accept);
  
  IloExpr expr(env);
  // Create objective function
  for (const auto& i : R)
  {
      expr += p[rmap[i]]; 
  }
  IloObjective obj(env, expr, IloObjective::Minimize);
  model.add(obj);
  expr.clear();
  
  
  // Create the solver object
  IloCplex cplex(model);
  env.out() << "Before" << endl;
  env.out() << model << endl;
  cplex.exportModel("Before.1.lp");
  
  solved = cplex.solve();

  if (solved)
  {
    // If CPLEX successfully solved the model, print the results
    std::cout << "\n\nCplex success!\n";
    std::cout << "\tStatus: " << cplex.getStatus() << "\n";
    std::cout << "\tObjective value: " << cplex.getObjValue() << "\n";

    // add new request to R, create variable p and corresponding constraint
    new_request = 23;
    R.push_back(new_request);
    rmap[new_request] = R.size() - 1;
    name << "p_" << new_request;
    p.add(IloNumVar(env,0,1,ILOBOOL,name.str().c_str()));
    name.str("");
    name << "accept_" << new_request;
    
    // These to lines don't work
    accept.add(IloRange());
    accept[rmap[new_request]] = IloRange(env,1,p[rmap[new_request]],1,name.str().c_str()); 
    
    // this line works
    //model.add(p[rmap[new_request]] == 1);
    
    name.str(""); // Clean name

    env.out() << "After" << endl;
    env.out() << model << endl;
    cplex.exportModel("After.1.lp");
    solved = cplex.solve();
  }
  
  expr.end();
  env.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the mistake myself. The constraints have to be added to the model, not only to the `IloRangeArrray`, which was previously added to the model. The lines

```
accept.add(IloRange());
accept[rmap[new_request]] = IloRange(env,1,p[rmap[new_request]],1,name.str().c_str());
```

have to be changed to:

```
IloRange rng(env,1,p[rmap[new_request]],1,name.str().c_str());
accept.add(rng);
model.add(rng);
```